# Intellij Ultimate: Spring boot application not fetching web resources in normal mode but fetching in mvn spring-boot:run

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

My Spring boot project is divided in two modules: core (Having all the core java logic, controller, security etc.) and UI(having all the JS and JSPs as well as the **"Spring Boot STARTER"** java class).
Now if I run directly this starter, I get error while loading UI page that:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Feb 19 12:45:51 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/sys_pda/pages/index.jsp
```

But if I run the application via **"mvn spring-boot:run"**, all works fine and UI gets loaded perfectly.

** UI pom has dependency of core.

Can you please help running this application normally.
[Error on UI, when I run normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTNfi.jpg)

Comment: Well, it is an expected behaviour. You are getting an 404 because app couldn't found that resource in that path. About the /error, it is showing the default error message, you can override that ugly error page with a custom one.

Comment: I am not concerned about the error page, the point is it shouldn't be searching for this error page. The application should be able to find **/sys_pda/pages/index.jsp**  page as its working and able to find this with spring-boot:run